# Docusign Software Page for MSI Missing?

Tags: docusignapi

My team is getting ready to use Docusign; however, i cant seem to find an MSI, so i can prep the deployment, does anyone know of the software page that I am missing ?

All the software pages seem to point to the windows store; however that is disabled on our system. Any one got the MSI or know of some non-listed Docusign  page that I can get the software from?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, which DocuSign plugin are you looking for? If you're looking for DocuSign for Word, SharePoint, or Outlook, an MSI is not available. You will need to get those from the Windows store, which may require working with your local IT group for approval and deployment.

If you're looking for the DocuSign Print Driver, that's available on the Support Center's Downloads page: https://support.docusign.com/en/downloads

If you're looking for DocuSign Retrieve, a link should have been provided by your Account Team.